# Why my object doesn't rotate continuously?

Tags: python, pygame, rotation

Error : So, I'm having a logic error.

I want my object called 'Claw' rotate (range : 10-170 degrees) back and forth.
But, somehow when Claw reached the angle of 170, the value of angle didn't decrease. It sticks at the angle of 170.

**Here is my Claw class**

```py
class Claw(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    
    def __init__(self,image,position):
       
        super().__init__()
        self.original_image = image #saved original image(unchangeable)
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect(center = position)

        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2(default_offset_claw_x, 0)
        self.position = position

        self.direction = LEFT
        self.angle = 10 #the first angle
        self.angle_speed = 2.5
        

    def update(self):
       # rect_center = self.position + self.offset #mid point
       # self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = rect_center)
        if self.direction == LEFT: #to the left
            self.angle += self.angle_speed
        elif self.direction == RIGHT:
            self.angle -= self.angle_speed
        

        #when it reaches an edge
        if self.angle > 170:
            self.angle = 170
            self.directon = RIGHT
        elif self.angle < 10:
            self.angle = 10
            self.direction = LEFT   

        print(self.angle, self.direction)  

**Here is my game main variables**

    default_offset_claw_x = 40
    LEFT = -1
    RIGHT = 1
```

**Here is my main**

```
#claw initialize
claw_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(current_path, "img\\claw.png"))
claw = Claw(claw_image, (screen_width//2, 110))
#game loop
running = True

while running:

    clock.tick(30)  # FPS = 30
    # Look at every event in the queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    
    gemstone_group.draw(screen) #draw all sprites in gemstone_group
    
    claw.update()
    claw.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update() #display update

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is missing an `i` in `directon`. It has to be `self.direction = RIGHT`. Anyway you can simplify the code:

```py
class Claw(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.angle += self.angle_speed * self.direction
        if self.angle > 170 or self.angle < 10:
            self.anlge = max(10, min(170, self.angle))
            self.direction *= -1
```